# Share the cookies between two openers with urllib2 and cookielib

Tags: python, cookies, proxy, urllib2

I am creating a script that will require me to use a proxy and requires cookie usage.

The script will visit both HTTP and HTTPS pages, meaning I need two URL openers for this.

However, I want the cookies of both openers to be shared by each other, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need 2 openers?  Make one and include handlers and proxies for both http and https and 1 cookie jar.  I am having no problems using 1 opener for all of my needs.

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = build_opener(
             HTTPHandler(), HTTPSHandler(), HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), 
             ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://user:passwd@proxy.example.com:80'}),
             ProxyHandler({'https': 'http://user:passwd@proxy.example.com:80'}))
```

For 2 openers, make 1 cookie jar and share it between them.

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
HTTPOpener = build_opener(
             HTTPHandler(), HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), 
             ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://user:passwd@proxy.example.com:80'}))
HTTPSOpener = build_opener(
             HTTPSHandler(), HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), 
             ProxyHandler({'https': 'http://user:passrd@proxy.example.com:80'}))
```